# Use domains in docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

Is it possible to configure multiple domains in a docker image pointing to localhost? For example, my website has two domains that reflect different languages. Now I would like to use these within a docker image to perform tests. On Windows I would enter this in Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts the following:

```html
127.0.0.1 domain.de
127.0.0.1 domain.com
```

I use nginx: alpine as an image. What exactly should I enter in /etc/hosts for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to touch `hosts` file? You need to configure `nginx` for a multi-host site. Maybe you need to modify `hosts` to your **host machine** if you want to redirect requests to the container.

Comment: I need multiple domains in my test environment for functional tests before deploying.

Comment: Could you explain, please, what tests environment do you use? Yes, probably, you need to edit `hosts` file, but it is out of the container and we need to figure out where is.

Comment: Thanks. I just found the solution: I have to use the `extra_hosts` option in my local docker-compose.yml and use the `add-host` option in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml.